# How to pass url query params in react native?

Tags: react-native, parameter-passing, fetch

How to pass params along with fetch request in react native.Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  }),
});
```

Read more about [Making Request](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#making-requests)

Comment: Sorry i am looking for something like this `fetch('https://mywebsute.com/endpoint + 'id')` .?Trying to pass params dynamically..How to do this?

Comment: Actually i'm get confused..i'm passing `id` from my `firstScreen` to `SecondScreen` and trying to access this in `SecondScreen` and it is working fine..But along with `fetch` request can i just give as `id` ??

Comment: In my first screen `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>this.props.navigation.navigate("SecondScreen",{id: user.data.id})}>` and in second screen `fetch('https:www.mywebiste.com/' + 'id')`..

Comment: You will not get the `id` directly in `SecondScreen` You have to get it like `fetch('https:www.mywebiste.com/' + this.props.navigation.state.params.id)`

Comment: U should add your code into the question, then the other could answer your question.